# Windows Log File Viewer (Tail) that displays lines in reverse order

Tags: windows, user-interface, reverse, tail, logfile

I am looking for a free Windows GUI log file viewer that can display lines in reverse order with the newest lines at the top of the screen.  Bonus points if it has an indication that there has been an update to the file.  Open source also a plus but not required.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

[TailForWin32](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/index.php) is open-source, works smoothly on multiple files, and can be set to beep or send email notifications on changes. It also accepts plugins, so you can configure weirder stuff.

Comment: I don't see that it can display the end of the file (newest lines) at the top of the window (reverse order).

Comment: I think you're right, lines are at the bottom. It hits the bonus points you're looking for. And it hits my bonus point of NOT being at the top (because I expect a log to be in historical order).

Comment: Its a personal preference but Windows Event Viewer puts the newest at the top.  Also your application buttons and menus are always at the top so your eyes don't have to move back and forth from the top to the button of the screen to go between the most important (newest) event and the features at the top of the application.

Comment: I use LogExpert (open source) but I wish it had the option to sort in reverse order.

Comment: TailForWin32 does not have search, or I just didn't find this feature.

Answer (score 1):

[TraceTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tracetool/) can do this quite well. Click the "Windows" menu item and select "Open Tail File...". TraceTool can do quite a bit more, but it's also a great open-source tail GUI.

[image]